# Search Engine Help

Tags: search-engine, lamp, mediawiki

I have a mediawiki installation that I've customized with some of my own extensions.  Here is the basic platform, pretty standard LAMP install.

- Ubuntu Server
- Apache 2
- Mediawiki 1.15
- PHP 5.2.6
- MySQL 5.0.67

For the actual MW search I use Lucene (EzMwLucene).  I also have custom extension that displays tabular data from a separate database within a MW page.  Lucene doesn't index this info (which, in my case is actually good because it would clutter your expected search results).  For this installation I didn't do anything to Lucene other than install it and wouldn't know how to customize it for my needs and it may be "too powerful".

At any rate, I need to create a search for the data in my other database.  I have a master table that is updated daily based on data stored in other (normalized) tables.  At the moment it is one of these searches that basically creates a SQL query based on the criteria you enter.  This is a lot of work, though.  I would like it to be more of a "type and submit" type search.

I don't think I need a comprehensive "cut & paste" type answer, but if anybody has something that I can google I would be very appreciative.  I don't need to recreate the wheel, which is what I would be doing if I followed what I see in google.

If you would like to see my master database, let me know, I would want to sanitize it to make me more anonymous (whatever that means).  Also, if you're familiar with MW and would like to see any of my extension code, again, let me know.

**TL;DR: need to make a custom search feature with LAMP (displayed in Mediawiki).  Any guidance appreciated.**

Thanks SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to add custom search? This will relate to the best answer.

For simplicity, you could use the Google Search Engine - http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Google_Custom_Search_Engine

Otherwise it sounds like you need to write a full-text query for the database.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I think I was looking for "full-text query".  I googled that and it looks promising.  It looks like the extension would replace the full-site search.  I have that one working as I want it.  I need a second search that will only be seen on one page of the wiki and will search a completely separate database.  I made this extension with a tag that renders a custom page (basically just a search form, then uses ajax to get returns on the same page).